# iOS Swift Segue from TableView Cell without Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am having trouble on performing a segue when you click on a tableView's cell. I am not using storyboard at all in the application (deleted the storyboard file), and was wondering how I could perform this segue.
Note:

1. My tableView is in a different file than the viewController that displays it. So in my ViewController i have this line:

   let tableView = MyTableView(restaurants_data: restaurants, frame:   CGRect(), style: .Plain)
   view.addSubview(tableView)
2. So since MyTableView.swift is the file where the didSelectRowAtIndexPath function is located at I cant do something like

   self.navigationController?.showViewController(destinationVC, sender:nil)

So, how do I perform a segue when the user clicks on the cell, given that I am using a custom TableView and my application is not using StoryBoard?
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Subclassing a `UITableView` may not be recommended: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10250358/1305067. If you want to encapsulate a `UITableView`, perhaps wrapping it a view controller and adding it to your view as a child view controller could do what you want.
As for accessing `navigationController`, pass it in as an argument to your `MyTableView` `init` method. BTW, without storyboard, there are no segues, AFAIK - so just use the usual `pushViewController` method.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference for the viewController inside your tableView

and initialise it in the viewController init
var controller : UIViewController

controller.presentViewController(viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: block?>)

Comment: that would not work because like I said above, the method "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" is inside a UITableView class, not a UITableViewController. UITableView doesn't contain the presentViewController method.

Comment: But `viewControllerToPresent.navigationController` does have the `presentViewController` method.

Comment: @paulvs but calling viewControllerToPresent.navigationController.pesentViewController(viewControllerToPresent: viewControllerToPresent., animated: Bool, completion ..) wouldn't make sense at all, would it'

Comment: @EzeGom Having the table view implement its own delegate doesn't sounds like a great design. However, if you want to or have to use this, you'll need to give the table view some way to pass on the cell selection event. I'd suggest defining a protocol: `ItemSelectedHandler` with a method `view:selectedItem:`, and injecting an instance of this when you create the table view.

Comment: @Benjohn: I changed the design and made it so that the ViewController where the table is being displayed contains is also the delegate and datasource for the table, is that a bad design practice? Any recommendations? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @EzeGom This is a pretty standard approach and is frequently fine.